# Android Studio: SQLite Helper doesn´t work

Tags: android, sqlite

I tried this code in a fragment instead of an activity, but it doesn´t work:

```
this.listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_easy);
    DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);
    databaseAccess.open();
    List<String> quotes = databaseAccess.getQuotes();
    databaseAccess.close();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, quotes); //android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
    this.listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Cannot resolve symbol "listView" and Constructor "ArrayAdapter(...)"

So I hope you know an answer, thanks in advance.

Comment: The listView was declared in the Activity not the Fragment, and ArrayAdapter needs to be imported in the header of a java file

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos but how? The listView is declared now, but now findviewbyid cannot be resolved... What to do with ArrayAdapter?

Comment: If you doing this at onCreateView and are inflating the ListView, you can findVBI in the result that will be the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Fragments, you have to inflate the layout as `View`

```
// inside onCreateView
View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.your_layout_name, container, false)
// layout which has listview                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and then initialize `listview` as

```
this.listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView_easy);
```

and `Fragment` doesn't have their own `context` so use `getActivity()` to create adapter as

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, quotes);
//                                                        ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Error at this line: DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);    - the error is getInstance() cannot be applied to Menu1 (that´s a fragment)

Comment: refer to second point and use `DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getActivity());`

Comment: and it says the database and array lines are redundant

Comment: still redundant

Comment: @J.Doe I guess that is just a warning for code optimization,

Comment: View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);      - unreachable statement, after I added a semicolon?

Comment: add the complete code , seems like you are adding this after some return statement